# How to reshape in PyTorch. [1, 257, 512] ->[1, 512, 16,16]

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

I am currently working on image generation using transformers.

I used the Vit part as it is for the encoder part.

In addition, I want to attach a transformer decoder and pass the encoder output, and put the output of the transformer decoder into the CNN decoder to create an image.

With:

```
image size = 128 * 128
patch_size = 8
d_model = 512
```

The output of the transformer decoder is `[1, 257, 512]`.

`[1,257,512]` => `hw/64 * 512` i want reshape `h/8 * w/8 * 512`, but I'm not sure how to reshape it.

How can I transform `257` into `256`?

i use

```
decoder_out = decoder_out.permute(0, 2, 1).view(1, self.d_model, 16, 16)
```